# How many times a webapp script can be called?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script which returns `JSON` from the content of a `spreadsheet`. The script is deployed as `a webapp run by the owner of the script`. The JSON is then used to feed a `Google Maps website` accessible by everybody.

> Is there any kind of limits on how many times the script can be called
>   by the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention wether the site has an apps-script gadget to retrieve data or not so I guess it hasn't.

The main limit you are going to meet is the total computing time if your script is called very often. The maximum for 1 day is 1 hour : looking at the usual execution time you can have a rough idea of the number of executions per day, and from there the number of requests.

Comment: The website retrieves the JSON through an AJAX call using the "exec?jsonp=?"-url of the script. The limit you are emphasizing seems to be the problem I will face. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the info... happy to know I had the right guess ;-) please consider accepting the answer.